# Twillio Programmable Voice calling App to App

Tags: android, ios, twilio, voip

My app uses the old TwillioSDK, and I am trying to update to new **TwillioProgrammable voice**.

But I am making calls between users, App to App, no numbers.
Is this possible with the new version? It seems you can only call numbers.

When using the old version, there used to be an "identity" concept.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409940/2437655 voice sdk still use identity map with firebase token to push notification calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I understand that, in fact, I thought I came across the same issue earlier today too.

However, you do still provide an identity for your users. When you generate the new [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) (rather than the old capability token) you add a grant to make outbound calls. There is no grant for inbound calls, however you do set an identity on the token itself. This is the identity of your user in the system.

Check out this example of creating an access token in Ruby to see where the identity is added:

```
token = Twilio::Util::AccessToken.new(
  account_sid,
  api_key,
  api_secret, 
  3600,
  identity
);

grant = Twilio::Util::AccessToken::VoiceGrant.new
grant.outgoing_application_sid = outgoing_application_sid
token.add_grant(grant)
```

Check out the documentation on [Twilio Access Tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) for more examples in other languages.